# accessing data from a joined table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :restaurant_address
  has_many :restaurant, through: :restaurant_address
end

class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :restaurant_address
  has_many :address, through: :restaurant_address
end

class Restaurant_Address > ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address
  belongs_to :restaurant
end
```

As you can see i have 3 tables. So far, inserting data works fine on individual tables. however, I am not getting the association I need on the `Restaurant_Address` table.  How would I set up my controller so that when I insert a new restaurant and address they automatically get associated in the `Restaurant_Address` table?

Comment: You should be using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` along with `fields_for`

Comment: Firstly: your Restaurant_address should be called RestaurantAddress (no underscore)

Comment: Secondly: do you have any fields on RestaurantAddress apart from the two _id fields? if not... then you don't need a model for it... and you don't need to use :through -> you should be using a has_and_belongs_to_many association

Comment: Thirdly: what do you have in your controller right now? What do you have in your form? I recommend googling "rails has_and_belongs_to_many forms" for ideas, and having a go at one of them. Come back to us if the solutions don't work for you :)

Comment: changed it to habtm now. but how would i then make rails do it's magic by viewing in on the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all the answers. i just sorta gave up on this model and went on a more "rails" approach using nested method techniques. but i did learn a lot from what i saw and realized that my design pattern though doable was unattainable at my current knoweldge level. thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Active Record relies heavily on conventions. A has_many association uses the plural form of the word, so it should be:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :restaurant_addresses
  has_many :restaurants, through: :restaurant_addresses
end

class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :restaurant_addresses
  has_many :addresses, through: :restaurant_addresses
end

class RestaurantAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address
  belongs_to :restaurant
end
```

Also, note that change to CamelCase on the RestaurantAddress class, this is the convention for models as well. The convention assumes that your table :restaurant_addresses has foreign keys address_id and restaurant_id! The ActiveRecord guide is awesome, you can mess around with it [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html).

Comment: class RestaurantAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :addresses
      belongs_to :restaurants
    end

Comment: Sorry syntax was off used the greater-than sign on the last one

Comment: Also, belongs_to uses the singular form of the word :address and :restaurant

Answer (score 0):

**has_many :through**

Further to `The Brofessor`'s answer, you'll want to ensure you appreciate the [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) association:

[image]

Although your associations look like they're setup correctly, I would suggest you have an issue with the naming of your class. Class names are handled with [`CamelCase`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase), whilst filenames are handled with [`snake_case`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case)

So, as `The Brofessor` pointed out, you'll need to do this:

```
#app/models/restaurant_address.rb
Class RestaurantAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
end
```

---

**Data**

In the sense of accessing data, if you have your models & tables set up correctly, you'll want to ensure you have the data set up to correctly manage it:

```
#app/controllers/restaurants_controller.rb
Class RestaurantsController < ApplicationController
   def show
        @restaurant = Restaurant.find params[:id]
        @restaurant.assresses #-> yields object with addresses inside
   end
end
```

--

**Associations**

Finally, I noticed your `address` association has been declared singularly.

Although I'm not 100% sure on this, I would say the address association needs to be plural, or at least if you're going to make it singular, you should have the `class_name` argument defined

To keep it safe, I would pluralize the `address` association:

```
#app/models/restaurant.rb
Class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    has_many :addresses
end
```

Comment: thanks. I did take into consideration all the naming conventions i missed, I did as you said though @restaurant.addresses but when i do i get an uninitalized constant Restaurant::Addresses error.